# Executing failed test automatically using Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have Regression Suit with 1000 Tests, but for every cycle, couple of my test cases are failing because ID not found error. Even though, respective ID is available but Webdriver could not click the ID (Same ID is for all 1000 Tests). But if I refresh the page It is working as expectedly.

I used below code:

```java
        if (existsId("id")==true){
            assertNotNull(bost.driver.findElement(By.id(id)));
        } else {
            bost.driver.navigate().refresh();                
            assertNotNull(bost.driver.findElement(By.id(id)));
        }
    }
}

public boolean existsId(String id) {
    try {
        bost.driver.findElement(By.id(id));
    } catch (Exception e) {
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I need  a code to re-run the test once it is failed due to assert command.
with the above code, webdriver is waiting for couple of seconds to execute the command so ultimately wait time is tooooo much.... compare with previous run.